# The matrix obtained after applying PCA consists of only imaginary numbers

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am using the following code to reduce dimensions of a 3600x3600 matrix to a 3600x1000 matrix using PCA. The original matrix does not have any imaginary numbers.

```
def reduce_dimensions_value(X, n_dim):
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

    X_mean = np.mean(X, axis=0)
    # cov_mat = np.cov(X)
    cov_mat = (X - X_mean).T.dot((X - X_mean)) / (X.shape[0]-1)
    #print('Covariance matrix \n%s' %cov_mat)
    
    eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)

    eig_pairs = [(np.abs(eig_vals[i]), eig_vecs[:,i]) for i in range(len(eig_vals))]

    # Sort the (eigenvalue, eigenvector) tuples from high to low
    eig_pairs.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

    # Visually confirm that the list is correctly sorted by decreasing eigenvalues
    #print('Eigenvalues in descending order:')
    #for i in eig_pairs:
    #    print(i[0])
        
    tot = sum(eig_vals)
    var_exp = [(i / tot)*100 for i in sorted(eig_vals, reverse=True)]
    cum_var_exp = np.cumsum(var_exp)
    
    n_new_dim = n_dim
    matrix_w = []
    for i in range(n_new_dim):
        print(eig_pairs[i][1])
        print(eig_pairs[i][0])
        matrix_w.append(eig_pairs[i][1].reshape(3600, 1))

    matrix_w = np.array(matrix_w)

    #matrix_w = np.hstack((eig_pairs[0][1].reshape(4,1),
    #                      eig_pairs[1][1].reshape(4,1)))

    matrix_w = np.squeeze(matrix_w)
    matrix_w = matrix_w.transpose()

    Y = X.dot(matrix_w)
    
    return Y

PCA_X = reduce_dimensions_value(X, 1000)
print(PCA_X[0])
```

However, the output is something like this:

> array([-4.81658724e+00+0.j, -4.13028635e+00+0.j,  2.43405608e+01+0.j,
> -1.92742145e+00+0.j, -4.49368603e+00+0.j, -4.99061600e+00+0.j,
> -1.28566607e+01+0.j, -3.62236186e+00+0.j,  4.07485063e+00+0.j,
> -1.80482208e+01+0.j, -3.92486670e+00+0.j,  4.24687064e+00+0.j,
> 1.89536391e+00+0.j, -1.02506089e+01+0.j, -1.04710117e+01+0.j,
> 9.52083442e+00+0.j,  2.17232343e+00+0.j, -4.55215051e+00+0.j,
> -2.09493058e-01+0.j, -2.43670185e+00+0.j,  3.63952624e+00+0.j,
> -6.38684716e+00+0.j,  1.32202407e+00+0.j, -6.29098486e+00+0.j,
> 5.86026339e+00+0.j,  1.62433151e+00+0.j,  1.84153583e+00+0.j,
> -6.63762632e-01+0.j,  3.39784194e-01+0.j,  1.92863554e+00+0.j,
> 2.17519568e+00+0.j, -3.47973361e+00+0.j, -1.86848135e+00+0.j,
> -3.51478560e+00+0.j, -8.66924929e-01+0.j,  1.90356026e+00+0.j,
> 9.58664258e-01+0.j,  3.18890980e+00+0.j, -3.16201758e-01+0.j,
> 5.94391055e-01+0.j, -4.80869790e-01+0.j, -1.93081070e+00+0.j,
> -6.88546242e-01+0.j, -1.18996924e+00+0.j,  1.03525818e-01+0.j,
> -1.34379936e+00+0.j,  6.33035936e-01+0.j, -4.37003776e+00+0.j,
> -2.20770604e+00+0.j, -1.10083713e+00+0.j, -3.11549255e+00+0.j,
> -2.01617907e-01+0.j, -3.32528208e+00+0.j,  2.98472471e+00+0.j,
> -5.19589281e-01+0.j,  2.58721305e-01+0.j,  2.48661846e+00+0.j,
> -8.04356030e-01+0.j, -2.89977032e+00+0.j,  2.46442668e+00+0.j,
> 2.43858921e+00+0.j,  4.66083052e-01+0.j,  6.37696323e-03+0.j,
> -3.51218640e+00+0.j, -5.66588837e-01+0.j,  3.72954017e-01+0.j,
> -3.09629950e+00+0.j, -6.84309926e-01+0.j,  1.99770892e-01+0.j, ... ])

I guess I might be wrong somewhere, but where could it be?

I applied PCA based on this tutorial:
https://www.kaggle.com/vipulgandhi/pca-beginner-s-guide-to-dimensionality-reduction

Comment: You seem to have commented out the line that generates a covariance matrix.  Eigenvalues will be complex if the matrix isn't  Hermitian/symmetric.

Comment: @MattTimmermans thank you very much for the comment. I followed all the steps in the tutorial. It was commented in the tutorial